# How to obtain the same behavior as the TabLayout on Google Play Store app?

Tags: android, material-design, android-tablayout

I create the sample project with **Action Bar Tabs** with **ViewPager** in **Android Studio 1.4**:

[image: Action Bar Tabs (with ViewPager) project]

In this example, we have a classic **[TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html)** that takes the **full width** of the screen regardless of its number of Tabs:

[image: Simple TabLayout]

I just want to **remove the default behavior** so that each tab fits its title content when the number of tabs **is more than three**. Also, the **TabLayout** width doesn't fit the screen but it **expands with the size of all tabs**.

This **behavior** it's exactly the same on **Google Play Store app**:

[image: Smart TableLayout]

Comment: are you try use `app:tabMode="scrollable"`  attribute in xml?

Comment: show you xml for more details

Comment: Very effective response !! Thank you. Answers below with a little more information for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try use `app:tabMode="scrollable"` attribute in xml
more information https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout